# How to derive the quantum Fisher information from the relative entropy?

Tags: information-theory, quantum-fisher-information, relative-entropy

The quantum relative entropy (QRE) between two states $\rho$ and $\sigma$ is given by
$$
S(\rho\|\sigma)=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho\ln\rho)-\operatorname{Tr}(\rho\ln\sigma)
$$
Now if $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are infinitesimally related i.e, $\sigma=\rho+\delta\rho$, and we assumed a differential parametrization of the density matrix $\rho(\lambda)$ by a vector $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n)$ such that $\delta\rho=\partial_i\rho~d\lambda_i$.

I know that the QRE is related to the quantum Fisher information metric $(F_{ij})$ by
$$
S(\rho\mid\mid\rho+\delta\rho)\simeq\frac{1}{2}F_{ij}d\lambda_id\lambda_j+(\dots)
$$
My calculation is leading me to the following result
$$
S(\rho\|\rho+\delta\rho)\simeq-\operatorname{Tr}(\delta\rho)+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr}(\delta\rho\rho^{-1}\delta\rho).
$$
where the first term is zero since $\operatorname{Tr}\rho=1$.

I am however unable to resolve the second term and obtain the standard form
$$
F_{ij}=2~\sum_{kl}\frac{\operatorname{Re}(\langle k|\partial_i\rho| l\rangle\langle l|\partial_j\rho| k\rangle)}{\theta_k+\theta_l},
$$
where the eigenvalues $\theta_k$ and eigenvectors $| k\rangle$ of the density matrix potentially depend on $\lambda$.

Comment: The discrepancy here is mildly related to the problems of consistently discretizing the Fisher information (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267074290_Discrete_densities_and_Fisher_information). There, the equivalent ways (due to derivative/integral properties) to define the FI for a continuous parameter lead to different FIs when discretized; here, equivalences that hold for classical probability distributions (again due to derivative/integral properties) change when different things are quantized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressing the derivative $\partial_i\rho$ in terms of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors will show us that these two are not equal. I will assume a full-rank density matrix $\rho$ to streamline the derivation.

Our first hint comes from writing $\rho^{-1}=\sum_k \theta_k^{-1}|k\rangle\langle k|$; then
$$\mathrm{Tr}(\delta\rho \rho^{-1}\delta\rho)=\sum_{kl}\frac{\langle l|\partial_i \rho|k\rangle\langle k|\partial_j\rho|l\rangle}{\theta_k}d\lambda_i d\lambda_j.$$
We need to change the numerator into the real part and the denominator into $\theta_k+\theta_l$ to recover the expression for quantum Fisher information.

We can decompose the derivatives into
$$\partial_i\rho=\sum_{m}\partial_i \theta_m|m\rangle\langle m|+\theta_m|\partial_i 
 m\rangle\langle m|+ \theta_m|m\rangle\langle \partial_i m|.$$ Taking a matrix element yields
\begin{align}
\langle l|\partial_i \rho|k\rangle=
\partial_i \theta_l \delta_{lk}+ \theta_k\langle l|\partial_i 
 k\rangle+ \theta_l\langle \partial_i l|k\rangle.
\end{align} Before we proceed, we use the trivial identity $0=\partial_i(\delta_{lk})=\partial_i\langle l|k\rangle=\langle \partial_i l|k\rangle+\langle  l|\partial_i k\rangle$ to separate our matrix elements into terms with $k=l$ and terms with $k \neq l$:
\begin{align}
\langle l|\partial_i \rho|k\rangle=
\partial_i \theta_l \delta_{lk}+ (1-\delta_{lk})(\theta_k-\theta_l)\langle l|\partial_i 
 k\rangle.
\end{align} The numerator now becomes
\begin{align}
\langle l|\partial_i \rho|k\rangle \langle k|\partial_j \rho|l\rangle=
\partial_i \theta_l \partial_j \theta_l \delta_{lk}+ (1-\delta_{lk})(\theta_k-\theta_l)^2 \langle l|\partial_i 
 k\rangle\langle k|\partial_j 
 l\rangle.
\end{align}

Now we can go in two directions: either try to show how this looks like the expression for quantum Fisher information, or take the real part of this and try to show how it becomes the trace expression. The latter is easier, so let's do it:
\begin{align}
2\sum_{kl}\frac{\Re (\langle k|\partial_i \rho|l\rangle \langle l|\partial_j \rho|k\rangle)}{\theta_k+\theta_l}&=2\sum_{kl}\frac{\Re (\langle l|\partial_i \rho|k\rangle \langle k|\partial_j \rho|l\rangle)}{\theta_k+\theta_l}\\
&=2\sum_{k=l}\frac{\partial_i\theta_k\partial_j\theta_l }{\theta_k+\theta_l}+2\sum_{k\neq l}\frac{(\theta_k-\theta_l)^2\Re (\langle l|\partial_i 
 k\rangle\langle k|\partial_j 
 l\rangle)}{\theta_k+\theta_l}
\\
&=\sum_{k}\frac{\partial_i\theta_k\partial_j\theta_k }{\theta_k}+\sum_{k\neq l}(\theta_k-\theta_l)^2\frac{\langle l|\partial_i 
 k\rangle\langle k|\partial_j 
 l\rangle + \langle \partial_i 
 k|l\rangle\langle \partial_j 
 l|k\rangle}{\theta_k+\theta_l}
\\
&=\sum_{k}\frac{\partial_i\theta_k\partial_j\theta_k }{\theta_k}+\sum_{k\neq l}(\theta_k-\theta_l)^2\frac{\langle l|\partial_i 
 k\rangle\langle k|\partial_j 
 l\rangle + \langle  
 k|\partial_i l\rangle\langle  
 l|\partial_j k\rangle}{\theta_k+\theta_l}
\\
&=\sum_{k}\frac{\partial_i\theta_k\partial_j\theta_k }{\theta_k}+2\sum_{k\neq l}(\theta_k-\theta_l)^2\frac{\langle l|\partial_i 
 k\rangle\langle k|\partial_j 
 l\rangle }{\theta_k+\theta_l}
\end{align}

As for the trace, it looks like
\begin{align}
\sum_{kl}\frac{\langle l|\partial_i \rho|k\rangle\langle k|\partial_j\rho|l\rangle}{\theta_k}&=\sum_{k}\frac{\partial_i\theta_k\partial_j\theta_k }{\theta_k}+\sum_{k\neq l}(\theta_k-\theta_l)^2\frac{\langle l|\partial_i 
 k\rangle\langle k|\partial_j 
 l\rangle }{\theta_k}
\end{align}

These results are manifestly different (for example, the second term can be complex in the expression for the trace but is manifestly real in the expression for the Fisher information).

---

Why are these expressions different? The derivation of the infinitesimal version of the relative entropy is much more tricky than the Bures metric, or infinitesimal fidelity, etc., because of the logarithms. One has to write
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Tr}[\rho \ln \rho-\rho\ln(\rho+\delta\rho)]=\mathrm{Tr}[\rho \ln \rho-\rho\ln(\rho(\mathbb{I}+\rho^{-1}\delta\rho))]
\end{align} and try to do a series expansion of $\ln(\rho(\mathbb{I}+\rho^{-1}\delta\rho))$. The problem is that one may not, in general, write $\ln(\rho(\mathbb{I}+\rho^{-1}\delta\rho))=\ln(\rho)+\ln(\mathbb{I}+\rho^{-1}\delta\rho)$ unless the commutator between $\rho$ and $\rho^{-1}\delta\rho$ vanishes, which it does not. This is why, even if the expressions may match for classical probability distributions, they do not in general for quantum states.

One needs to invoke the symmetric logarithmic derivatives to generally talk about a metric. See for example Eqs. (58-59) and the preceeding discussions [here](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1907.06628).

To do a proper derivation we need to be able to take the derivative of the logarithm of a matrix. See [this math-SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/723262/889261) and [this math overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/231635) and references therein; it's tricky! The components of the metric induced by the QRE can be defined by derivatives of the QRE with respect to the underlying parameters (this is how a metric is found classically from the relative entropy, see e.g. [this paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1612.07986) eq. 2.20)
$$g_{ij}=-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda^\prime_j}\mathrm{Tr}(\rho\ln\rho-\rho\ln\rho^\prime)\big|_{\rho=\rho^\prime},$$ where $\rho$ depends on $\lambda$ and $\rho^\prime$ depends on $\rho^\prime$ (I have switched from the $\sigma$ notation to make it easier to see that $\sigma\to\rho$ when $\lambda^\prime\to\lambda$). Product rule follows normally for matrix functions, derivatives commute with traces, so we are left with only contributions from the second term
$$g_{ij}=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \lambda_i }\frac{\partial \ln\rho^\prime}{ \partial \lambda^\prime_j}\right)\bigg|_{\rho=\rho^\prime}=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \lambda_i }\frac{\partial \ln\rho}{ \partial \lambda_j}\right).$$
This is exactly the expression for the QFI if one chooses the "symmetric logarithmic derivative" as $\frac{\partial \ln\rho}{ \partial \lambda_j}$ in this expression.

---

The standard procedure for deriving the quantum Fisher information is to write
$$\partial_i \rho=\frac{L_i\rho+\rho L_i}{2}$$ for the symmetric logarithmic derivative $L$, which can be proven to always exist and be Hermitian and in general depends on the underlying parameters $\lambda$. We can write an explicit solution as
$$L_i=2\sum_{kl}\frac{\langle k|\partial_i\rho|l\rangle}{\theta_k+\theta_l}|k\rangle\langle l|,$$ where a straightforward computation using orthogonality of the eigenstates and two resolutions of the identity verifies
$$L_i\rho+\rho L_i=2\sum_{kl}\frac{\langle k|\partial_i\rho|l\rangle}{\theta_k+\theta_l}|k\rangle\langle l|(\theta_k+\theta_l)=2\partial_i \rho.$$
Then the quantum Fisher information takes the form
$$F_{ij}=\mathrm{Tr}[\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \lambda_i}L_j]=\mathrm{Tr}[\rho(L_iL_j+L_jL_i)]/2.$$ The expression in the question takes the form
\begin{align}\mathrm{Tr}(\delta\rho \rho^{-1}\delta\rho)&=\sum_{ij}\mathrm{Tr}\left(\frac{L_i\rho+\rho L_i}{2}\rho^{-1} \frac{L_j\rho+\rho L_j}{2}\right)d\lambda_i d\lambda_j\\
&=\sum_{ij}\mathrm{Tr}\left(2\rho L_iL_j+\rho L_jL_i+\rho L_i \rho^{-1}L_j\rho\right)d\lambda_i d\lambda_j/4
\\
&=\sum_{ij}\mathrm{Tr}\left[F_{ij}-\mathrm{Tr}\left(\rho\frac{ L_jL_i- L_i \rho^{-1}L_j\rho}{4}\right)\right]d\lambda_i d\lambda_j.
\end{align} This explicitly shows the error between the two expressions due to $\mathrm{Tr}\left(\rho\frac{ L_jL_i- L_i \rho^{-1}L_j\rho}{4}\right)\neq 0$. Again, if all of the states and their derivatives were just probability distributions, everything would commute and the latter term would vanish.

---

At this point I have not proven that $L_j$ can replace $\frac{\partial \ln\rho}{ \partial \lambda_j}$ in the trace expression for derivatives of the QRE; it is highly unlikely that $L_j=\frac{\partial \ln\rho}{ \partial \lambda_j}$ holds in general because that would make solving the matrix logarithm derivative problem too easy. This is the crucial missing step required to connect the QFI and the QRE and is probably why people don't often derive the QFI from the QRE. Yes, there are classical/quantum-correspondence reasons for choosing the symmetric logarithmic derivative here, while other choices for the logarithmic derivative lead to other quantum Fisher information matrices. One should always choose one that yields a proper metric on the space of quantum states but even that is insufficient to single out a particular constrution. See e.g., the above quoted [article](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1907.06628)

> The classical Fisher information is the unique Riemannian metric on the space of classical probability distribtions that has the
> property of contraction under coarse graining. However, in the
> quantum-mechanical case the possibility of non-commuting
> operators breaks this uniqueness, and instead we obtain a family of metrics. It is therefore interesting to explore some
> alternative quantum extensions of the Fisher information.

My conclusion is thus: the curvature of the quantum relative entropy is given by the quantum Fisher information if the matrix derivative of the logarithm in the former is given by the same logarithmic derivative used in the latter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this beautifully presented answer. It couldn't be better than this. I just want to know whether there are some example of the choice of identifying matrix derivative of the logarithm of density matrix as the Logarithmic derivative in the literature. How is this choice compatible with the derivation of the Bures metric from the Fidelity.

Comment: @m1rohit unfortunately I'm not sure off the top of my head. I can point you to the article quoted in my answer for discussing right logarithmic derivative vs symmetric logarithmic derivative

Comment: It will help if you can show that this choice of the Logarithmic derivative required in the relative entropy is a solution to the original defining equation of SLD? I am still trying to work it out.

Comment: @m1rohit not sure if this is your problem, but let's try. If $\rho$ and $L_i$ commute, $\rho^{-1}\partial \rho/\partial \theta=L_i$. That's a differential equation solved by $\rho\propto e^{\theta L}$ and is equivalent to $\partial \ln \rho/\partial \theta=L_i$. That is the connection between logarithmic derivative and SLD

Comment: I was asking how to show that $$ L_i=\frac{\partial \ln\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}\neq \rho^{-1}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}\neq \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}\rho^{-1}$$ satisfies $$ L_i\rho+\rho L_i=2\partial_i\rho$$

Comment: Please forgive me If I am wrong. But in your last comment you assumed that $\rho$ and $L_i=\rho^{-1}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}=\rho^{-1}\delta\rho$ commutes. But you falsified this assumption right from the beginning of your answer.

Comment: @m1rohit I'm starting from the fact that you can always define a Hermitian $L_i$ such that $2\partial \rho/\partial \lambda_i=L_i \rho+\rho L_i$. From there, *if* $\rho L_i=L_i\rho$, we can rearrange to get $\rho^{-1} \partial \rho/\partial \lambda_i= L_i$, which is satisfied by $\rho\propto e^{\lambda_i L_i}$ (the derivative just gives $L_i \rho$). But one cannot do that if $\rho$ and $L_i$ do not commute! The definition of $L_i$ from $2\partial \rho/\partial \lambda_i=L_i \rho+\rho L_i$ is always valid, while defining $L_i$ as $\rho^{-1} \delta \rho$ does not always work

Comment: @m1rohit so: only when $L_i$ and $\rho$ commute can we write $L_i=\partial \ln \rho/\partial \lambda_i$.

Comment: After your last comment I can gather the following if $[\rho,\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}]=0$ then we get $$S(\rho\mid\mid\rho+\delta\rho)=\frac{1}{2}Tr[\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}\rho^{-1}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\lambda_j}]d\lambda_i d\lambda_j=\frac{1}{2}Tr[\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}\frac{\partial\ln\rho}{\partial\lambda_j}]d\lambda_i d\lambda_j=\frac{1}{2}Tr[\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}L_j]d\lambda_i d\lambda_j=g^F_{ij}d\lambda_i d\lambda_j$$

Comment: Where it was derived from the defining equation by you that $L_i=\frac{\partial\ln\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}$ is the SLD given $[\rho,\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\lambda_i}]=[\rho,L_i]=0$

Comment: I infer that the condition $[\rho,L_i]=0$ is crucial to obtain the correct Fisher information metric from the relative entropy. Can you shed some light on the physical interpretation of the above commutation relation?

Comment: These expressions have resemblance with the classical ones!

Comment: @m1rohit that happens when $\rho$ is a classical probability distribution: only the eigenvalues depend on $\lambda_i$, such that $|\partial_i k\rangle=0$. It also happens when the state is unchanged by the parameter, such that $L_i=0$, and other trivial examples. For unitary evolution with $U=e^{i G}$ we required $[\rho,[\rho,G]]=0$, which is very stringent and could have trivial solutions like $\rho$ being convex combinations of eigenstates of $G$ (and thus unchanged by the evolution)

Comment: I am asking why only in these special conditions does the Hessian of quantum relative entropy agrees with the quantum Fisher Information metric? In other cases there seems to have additional contribution from other terms.

Comment: I sincerely thank you for continuing this enlightening discussion.

Comment: @m1rohit I don't have any physical answer, just that the two expressions agree when $\rho$ looks like a classical probability distribution

Comment: Can you point me to an explicit example where $\rho$ looks like a classical probability distribution? I want to do some hand on calculations.

Comment: @m1rohit I mean things like $\rho(\{\lambda_i\})=\sum_k p_k(\{\lambda_i\})|k\rangle\langle k|$; the eigenvalues depend on the parameters but the eigenstates do not. This happens in loss estimation, for example https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.79.040305

Comment: @m1rohit here's a recent paper about quantum states with classical probability distributions in the context of metrology https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2023-05-11-998/

Comment: Thanks a lot I will surely go through it. It would have been nice to learn more from you. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I came across this work [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/003448779390043E). There it is mentioned in Lemma $2$ page $90$ that one can break the differential $d\rho$ into a commutative and a non commutative part v.i.z $$d\rho=d_c\rho+[\rho,\Omega]$$ where $$[d_c\rho,\rho]=0$$ and $$ d_c\rho=d\rho\mid_{\text{commutant}(\rho)}$$. Further $\Omega$ is anti Hermitian. I want your comment on how to redo the above derivation using this. I am especially facing problem with the separation of the logarithm.

Comment: @m1rohit I don't think this changes anything, because we still don't have any good identities for logarithms of sums of noncummuting matrices $d_c\rho$ and $[\rho,\Omega]$

Comment: I am back again. Probably this is my last attempt. I recently found this matrix identity $$ \ln(A+xB)-\ln(A)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{A+u\mathbb{I}}.xB.\frac{1}{A+xB+u\mathbb{I}}du$$, Where $A$ and $B$ are matrices and $x$ is a parameter. $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity matrix. I am trying to use this to redo the above derivation. For small $\delta\rho$ one can expand the inverse matrix thus obtained. I want your comments on this.

Comment: I just found out from page $407$ eqn($15.21$) of this [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometry-of-quantum-states/46B62FE3F9DA6E0B4EDDAE653F61ED8C) that the above procedure will reproduce the Kubo Mori metric. Now can you show that if $[\rho,\delta\rho]=0$ then the Kubo-Mori metric reduces to the Fisher information metric.

Comment: @m1rohit sure, when $[\rho,\delta \rho]=0$ then all of the metrics are the same. My quoted article above even has a section on Kubo-Mori (https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06628), which defines yet *another* logarithmic derivative. It is easy to see that eq. (202) there and the standard QFI (95) are both proportional to $Tr[(\partial \rho)^2\rho^{-1}]$ when the commutation condition is satisfied

Comment: From our previous discussion we know that if $[\rho,\delta\rho]=0$ Then the SLD can be written as
$$
 L_i=\partial_i\ln\rho=\int^{\infty}_{0}\left[\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\partial_i\rho\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\right]du
$$

Comment: and hence the QFI metric becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
&&g^F_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}Tr[(\partial_i\rho) L_j]d\lambda_id\lambda_j=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int^{\infty}_{0}Tr\left[\partial_i\rho\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\partial_j\rho\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\right]du\right)d\lambda_id\lambda_j\notag\\
&&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int^{\infty}_{0}Tr\left[\delta\rho\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\delta\rho\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\right]du\right)\notag\\
&&=g^{KM}(\delta\rho,\delta\rho)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Where $g^{KM}$ is the Kubo Mori metric. Is this observation consistent?

Comment: @m1rohit yes! You just have to massage the KM as well, because it's defined with $\rho^x d\lambda$ and $\rho^{1-x} d\lambda$ with an integral $\int_0^1 dx$, but it's all the same here because we can commute all the $\rho$ operators around to cancel the $x$ and the integral then gives unity

Comment: My expression matches with page 407 eqn(15.21) of this [Book](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Geometry_of_Quantum_States.html?id=sYswDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&gboemv=1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) I am unable to realise how this expression is same as eqn $(202)$ of $1907.06628$. Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: @m1rohit sorry I don't have the book and the google books preview doesn't show me that page. But I'm sure you can do it on your own! The trick is moving things that commute outside of the integral if possible, such that the integrals are things that can be done (for example, you can perform the integral $\int_0^\infty (\rho+u\mathbb{I})^{-2} du=1/\rho$ analytically)

Comment: Thanks for the Identity. For sake of completeness, I am giving the details from the book below. I think the two definition are for KM and BKM metrics

Comment: For matrices $A$ and $B$ we know that
\begin{equation}
\ln(A+xB)-\ln{A}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{A+u}xB\frac{1}{A+xB+u}du\notag\\
\end{equation}
It follows that
\begin{equation}
\partial_x\ln(\rho+x A)\mid_{x=0}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\rho+u}A\frac{1}{\rho+u}du
\end{equation}
with this result in hand it is straightforward to compute that 
\begin{equation}
 -\partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\beta}S(\rho+\alpha A\mid\mid\rho+\beta B)\mid_{\alpha=\beta=0}=\int_{0}^{\infty}Tr\left[A\frac{1}{\rho+u}B\frac{1}{\rho+u}du\right]
\end{equation}

Comment: This is precisely the definition for Kubo-Mori scalar product $g^{KM}(A,B)(\rho)$.

Comment: I figured it out . When $[\rho,\delta\rho]=0$ the Bogoliubov Logarithmic Derivative given in eqn$(202)$ of $(arxiv.org/abs/1907.06628),$ is identical with the Fisher Logarithmic derivative given above. Thus the BKM Information metric becomes

Comment: \begin{eqnarray}
&&I^{BKM}_{i j}= \int_0^1 Tr\left[\rho^x B_{\theta_i}^{\dagger}\rho^{1-x}B_{\theta_j}\right] dx\notag\\
&&= \int_0^1 Tr\left[\rho^x L_i^{\dagger}\rho^{1-x}L_j\right] dx\notag\\
&&= \int_0^1 Tr\left[\rho^x \rho^{1-x}L_iL_j\right] dx\notag\\
&&= Tr[\rho L_iL_j]=g^F_{ij}\notag\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Please check. I have two more questions that will complete my project. I hope you can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Now I want to explore the general case when $\delta\rho=\delta_c\rho+[\rho,\Omega]$. Substituting this above I get the following terms

Comment: \begin{eqnarray}
 &&g^{KM}(\delta\rho,\delta\rho)=\left(\int^{\infty}_{0}Tr\left[\delta_c\rho\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\delta_c\rho\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\right]du\right)+\left(\int^{\infty}_{0}Tr\left[[\rho,\Omega]\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\delta_c\rho\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\right]du\right)\notag\\
&&+\left(\int^{\infty}_{0}Tr\left[\delta_c\rho\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}[\rho,\Omega]\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\right]du\right)+\left(\int^{\infty}_{0}Tr\left[[\rho,\Omega]\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}[\rho,\Omega]\frac{1}{\rho+u\mathbb{I}}\right]du\right)
 \end{eqnarray}

Comment: Going by the [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/003448779390043E). I can Identify the first term above as the Fisher Information metric for the commutant. I am yet to figure out how to carve out a WYD information metric from the rest. I need your comments on this. Thanks.

Comment: The second and third term above are same. This can be seen by using the property of Trace. It simplifies to zero. As $Tr[L_c[\rho,\Omega]]=0$. Where $L_c=\delta_c\ln\rho$ is the commutant SLD.

Comment: I am clueless on how to simplify the last term?